# Specify the number of table rows in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to show the first 5 rows of my table when I execute shiny. The executable code is below. You can see that by default it shows the first 8 rows. However, if I vary the "number of clusters", it can reach up to 34 clusters. Therefore, the table would be very large. I would like to leave it configured to show at most the first 5 rows. If you have more, consequently you have a "button" to go to the next five rows.

Could someone help me solve this problem ??

Thank you so much friends.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                                                                                                                                 + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

function.clustering<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  if (Filter1==2){
    Q1<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25)) 
    Q3<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.75))
    L<-Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    S<-Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    df_1<-subset(df,Waste>L[1]) 
    df<-subset(df_1,Waste<S[1])
  }

  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 


  #Number of clusters
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Localization
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)

  #Scatter Plot
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
  g<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4)
  Centro_View<- g +  geom_text(data=df, mapping=aes(x=eval(Longitude), y=eval(Latitude), label=Waste), size=3, hjust=-0.1)+ geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes(Longitude, Latitude), color= "green", size=4) + geom_text(data=df1, mapping = aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, label = 1:k), color = "black", size = 4)
  plotGD<-print(Centro_View + ggtitle("Scatter Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))

  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Plot" = plotGD,
    "Coverage" = coverage
  ))
}
function.LetControl <- function(coverage) {
  m <- mean(coverage[, 1])
  MR <- mean(abs(diff(coverage[, 1])))
  d2 <- 1.1284
  LIC <- m - 3 * (MR / d2)
  LSC <- m + 3 * (MR / d2)
  plot(
    coverage[, 1],
    type = "b",
    pch = 16,
    ylim = c(LIC - 0.1 * LIC, LSC + 0.5 * LSC),
    axes = FALSE
  )
  axis(1, at = 1:35)
  axis(2)
  box()
  grid()
  abline(h = MR,
         lwd = 2)
  abline(h = LSC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
  abline(h = LIC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Clustering "),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(h3("Generation of clustering")),

      radioButtons("filter1", h3("Waste Potential"),
                   choices = list("Select all properties" = 1, 
                                  "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                   selected = 1),

      radioButtons("filter2", h3("Coverage do cluster"),
                   choices = list("Use default limitations" = 1, 
                                  "Do not limite coverage" = 2
                   ),selected = 1),

      tags$hr(),

      helpText(h3("Are you satisfied with the solution?")),
      helpText(h4("(1) Yes")),
      helpText(h4("(2) No")),
      helpText(h4("(a) Change the number of clusters")),
      sliderInput("Slider", h3("Number of clusters"),
                  min = 2, max = 34, value = 8),
      helpText(h4("(b) Change the filter options"))
    ),

    mainPanel(

      uiOutput("tabela"),  
      plotOutput("ScatterPlot"),
      plotOutput("LetCoverage"),

    )))

server <- function(input, output) {

  f1<-renderText({input$filter1})
  f2<-renderText({input$filter2})


  Modelclustering<-reactive(function.clustering(df,input$Slider,1,1))

  output$tabela <- renderUI({
  data_table_1 <- req(Modelclustering())[[1]]
  x <- kable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE)
  x <- kable_styling(kable_input = x, full_width = FALSE)
   HTML(x)
  })


  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
  Modelclustering()[[2]]
  })

  output$LetCoverage <- renderPlot({
    function.LetControl(Modelclustering()[[3]])
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much friends.

Comment: Just a hint: `ggplot2` is part of `tidyverse`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a kable for your table output, could you try a dataTable instead?

If you do that, you can limit the number of rows that are shown, meaning the user would have to click to the next page to see the next 5 clusters.

Specifically, the pageLength option in dataTable is what you are looking for:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
##Need to install this package if you don't have it
library(DT)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                                                                                                                                 + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

function.clustering<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  if (Filter1==2){
    Q1<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25)) 
    Q3<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.75))
    L<-Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    S<-Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    df_1<-subset(df,Waste>L[1]) 
    df<-subset(df_1,Waste<S[1])
  }

  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 


  #Number of clusters
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Localization
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)

  #Scatter Plot
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
  g<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4)
  Centro_View<- g +  geom_text(data=df, mapping=aes(x=eval(Longitude), y=eval(Latitude), label=Waste), size=3, hjust=-0.1)+ geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes(Longitude, Latitude), color= "green", size=4) + geom_text(data=df1, mapping = aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, label = 1:k), color = "black", size = 4)
  plotGD<-print(Centro_View + ggtitle("Scatter Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))

  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Plot" = plotGD,
    "Coverage" = coverage
  ))
}
function.LetControl <- function(coverage) {
  m <- mean(coverage[, 1])
  MR <- mean(abs(diff(coverage[, 1])))
  d2 <- 1.1284
  LIC <- m - 3 * (MR / d2)
  LSC <- m + 3 * (MR / d2)
  plot(
    coverage[, 1],
    type = "b",
    pch = 16,
    ylim = c(LIC - 0.1 * LIC, LSC + 0.5 * LSC),
    axes = FALSE
  )
  axis(1, at = 1:35)
  axis(2)
  box()
  grid()
  abline(h = MR,
         lwd = 2)
  abline(h = LSC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
  abline(h = LIC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Clustering "),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(h3("Generation of clustering")),

      radioButtons("filter1", h3("Waste Potential"),
                   choices = list("Select all properties" = 1, 
                                  "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                   selected = 1),

      radioButtons("filter2", h3("Coverage do cluster"),
                   choices = list("Use default limitations" = 1, 
                                  "Do not limite coverage" = 2
                   ),selected = 1),

      tags$hr(),

      helpText(h3("Are you satisfied with the solution?")),
      helpText(h4("(1) Yes")),
      helpText(h4("(2) No")),
      helpText(h4("(a) Change the number of clusters")),
      sliderInput("Slider", h3("Number of clusters"),
                  min = 2, max = 34, value = 8),
      helpText(h4("(b) Change the filter options"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      ##uiOutput("tabela"), 
      DTOutput("tabela"),  
      plotOutput("ScatterPlot"),
      plotOutput("LetCoverage"),

    )))

server <- function(input, output) {

  f1<-renderText({input$filter1})
  f2<-renderText({input$filter2})


  Modelclustering<-reactive(function.clustering(df,input$Slider,1,1))

  # output$tabela <- renderUI({
  #   data_table_1 <- req(Modelclustering())[[1]]
  #   x <- kable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE)
  #   x <- kable_styling(kable_input = x, full_width = FALSE)
  #   HTML(x)

  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    data_table_1 <- req(Modelclustering())[[1]]
    x <- datatable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)],
                options = list(
                  paging =TRUE,
                  pageLength =  5
                )
      )
    return(x)
  })


  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelclustering()[[2]]
  })

  output$LetCoverage <- renderPlot({
    function.LetControl(Modelclustering()[[3]])
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I got your app to work now. This should work, it will only show 5 clusters no matter how many you set in your input. If you want to change this, just add a new input slider or control widget.

I commented out your code and added my code. I changed on the UI and Server side.

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer. Could you try again to get the executable code above?
I did what you told me but I couldn't, do you have to change anything else? If you can try to used the executable code above to show me. Thank you!

Comment: @Jovani Souza - I updated my answer to include working code. This should do what you wanted, limit the table output to only 5 clusters. You'll have to format the table with the columns you want/ don't want.

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer. It worked, however I wanted to correctly sort the table. Leave: cluster, properties, coverage_meters and potential_waste. Also, can you leave it centralized?

Comment: @JovaniSouza - I updated the table source to match what you had. If you want to do some more formatting, you'll have to look at the options for DT and format it accordingly. 

If my response answers what you were looking for, don't forget to hit accept! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much friend.